# Is there a way to remove some options from Android system settings?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't find a way to explain what I need using words, so I'll use images instead.

What I want is to have the user open Accessibility settings and enable Window Change Detecting Service, but I only want this service to appear, nothing else.

i.e: When the user is directed to accessibility settings by my app, instead of seeing this:
[image]

I want them to see this:

[image]

This is the original code:

```
 Intent changeSettings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
 startActivityForResult(changeSettings, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to create your own build of Android that has a Settings app that looks the way that you want.

Otherwise:

- Apps cannot control what options appear on that screen.
- The exact set of options that appear on that screen will vary by device model and OS version. So, for example, the Samsung Galaxy S9 edition of that screen looks different:

[image: S9 Accessibility Settings]

Comment: So what do you think is the alternative way to make it easier for the user to enable my service? I'm betting that most users won't know which service they have to enable even when I direct them to it beforehand.

Comment: @User104163: "So what do you think is the alternative way to make it easier for the user to enable my service?" -- I would recommend not having such a service in the first place. [It does not work well on many devices](https://medium.com/nala-money/the-bifurcation-of-android-6fa1cced074d), and Google has indicated that it might start banning such apps unless they are truly for accessibility. Beyond that, though, you might provide detailed instructions for a few device models and hope that the user's device follows the pattern established by one of them.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do what this service does (detect when a user opens an app and tell my app what it is) besides running a loop in the background 24/7 to check for UI changes every 0.1 seconds which eats up a phone's battery and performance.

Comment: Is there a way for my app to open the Window Change Detecting Service by itself? I mean instead of the user clicking on Window Change Detecting Service and then pressing the switch to enable it, they are immediately directed to just pressing the switch.

Comment: @User104163: "Is there a way for my app to open the Window Change Detecting Service by itself?" -- there is no requirement for there to be such a screen.

Comment: Surely there has to be way? Like **Intent goThere = new Intent(open the Window Change Detecting Service somehow);** and then **startActivity(goThere);**

Comment: @User104163: Again, there is no requirement for there to be such a screen. Even if there is, there is no requirement for there to be an `Intent` that takes the user there. And the answer can vary across the 26,000+ Android device models. Device manufacturers can do what they want with the Settings app, with very few limitations.

Comment: @User104163: Even for the `Intent` that you are using, there is no requirement that it must work on all devices, which is why [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings?hl=en#ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS) warns you "In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.".

Comment: You mean this intent **Intent changeSettings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);** ?

Comment: @User104163: Correct. You need to wrap that in a `try`/`catch` block and deal with the possible `ActivityNotFoundException`.